Where can I find the book Haïm Brezis: Un mathématicien juif by Jacques Vauthier?
This year marks the passing of Haïm Brezis, and I would like to explore his life and work through this publication.
I tried to find it in several bookstores, in online format, but I really couldn't find it.
Does anyone have a digital copy of this book?

this bookstore sells it for € 19 (at least that's what the web site says, no idea if they will actually deliver); alternatively, many libraries have it.

@CarloBeenakker Unfortunately the bookstore does not ship to Brazil and these libraries are not located in Brazil either. I will wait to see if anyone would have a copy.

the book has been scanned by Google, but it is still under copyright, so no digital version is available.
